# cocos2d autoremove sprite after animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to cocos2d and to iphone development at all. I want to create some animation, when some physical object with it's sprite is destroyed (for example to show a splash). And i want to to make some object i will say to: run the animation and destroy yourself when done. Then i want to forget about this object - it should be destroyed automatically when animation is finished. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CCSequence to create a list of actions.  The first action you do should be your regular action (or sequence).  The second action should be CCCallFuncND action, where you can call a cleanup function and pass the given sprite.

Off the top of my head I'd do something like this:

```
CCSprite* mySpriteToCleanup = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySprite.png"];
[self addChild:mySpriteToCleanup];

// ... do stuff

// start the destroy process
id action1 = [CCIntervalAction actionWithDuration:0];  // the action it sounds like you have written above.
id cleanupAction = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cleanupSprite:) data:mySpriteToCleanup];
id seq = [CCSequence actions:action1, cleanupAction, nil];
[mySpriteToCleanup runAction:seq];
```

and in the cleanup function:

```
- (void) cleanupSprite:(CCSprite*)inSprite
{
    // call your destroy particles here
    // remove the sprite
    [self removeChild:inSprite cleanup:YES];
}
```

You could add in another action between these two actions as well for your destroy particle actions instead of calling that in the end function.

Comment: Very nice. In cocos2D 2.0 you can also use blocks:                         `CCAction *cleanupAction = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                            [mySpriteToCleanup removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
                        }];`

Answer (score 3):

The convenient way is using custom `RemoveNode` action, that removes the running `CCNode` object (`CCSprite` is also `CCNode`).

```
//Remove the node from parent and cleanup
@interface RemoveNode : CCActionInstant
{}
@end

@implementation RemoveNode
-(void) startWithTarget:(id)aTarget
{
    [super startWithTarget:aTarget];
    [((CCNode *)target_) removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}

@end
```

Place it in the CCSequence last parameter. For example, sprite will be removed after fade out:

```
[mySprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:
[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5], [RemoveNode action], nil]];
```

Comment: In Cocos2d 2.1, I had to tweak this to `[(CCNode *)_target removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];`