# Cocos2D setvisible =no after animation finishes

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

In my code asteroids coming toward to the ship,
I want to implement  explosion animation if laser hits the asteroid. 
Asteroid should run explosion animation and switch to invisible mode.

Without animation when target is hit, target successfully switches to invisible mode. Without setting object to  invisible, animation runs great. When I put it together because of procedural code without seeing animation it quickly set object to invisible.

How can I both see the animation then set it to invisible mode. (targets aka asteroids are in various speeds some of them are too fast while others slow)
The idea to put target to invisible is prevent them hitting to ship.

I tried this question&answer [cocos2d autoremove sprite after animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174445/cocos2d-autoremove-sprite-after-animation) didnt work

```
for (CCSprite *asteroid in _asteroids) 
{        
     if (!asteroid.visible) continue;

        for (CCSprite *shipLaser in _shipLasers)
        {                        
            if (!shipLaser.visible) continue;

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(shipLaser.boundingBox, asteroid.boundingBox)) 
            {                
                [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"explosion_large.caf"];

                //explosion zombie animation starts 
                NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
                for(int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) 
                {
                    [walkAnimFrames addObject:
                     [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zombieexplodes%d.png", i]]];
                }
                CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation 
                                         animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];


                _dieAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                               [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

                [asteroid runAction:_dieAction];
                //explosion zombie ends

                [self addPoint];

                //change meme to woohoo.png   
                [_ship setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: @"woohoo.png"]];

                shipLaser.visible = NO;
                [asteroid setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: @"zombieexplodes13.png"]];
                //asteroid.visible=NO;


                continue;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style on calling:

```
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation 
                         animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
id animate  = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
id calFuncN = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(explodeAnimDone:)];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions:animate, calFuncN,nil];

[asteroid runAction:sequence];
```

Disable sprite when your animation is done.

```
-(void)explodeAnimDone:(id)sender
{
    CCNode *myNode = (CCNode*)sender;
    myNode.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I like CCCallBlockN sample: 
CCCallBlockN *calFuncN = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
        node.visible = false;
    }

Comment: @zeiteisen, thanks for this info, It reduces number of lines to code.

Comment: Like Matthijs Hollemans said: laziness is a programmer’s greatest virtue :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done game dev in Cocoa2D, but when I made games like this I would have a separate explosion object that removed itself when its animation ended. So you should generate an explosion object and turn the asteroid invisible right away. If you can't get autoremove on animation finish to work, time the explosion and then set a timer on your explosion object to remove itself.

I noticed that you're turning asteroids invisible... you should remove them instead - they still take up memory when they are invisible.